# firebase messaging package error in IOS Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods, podfile

App works fine but when I add firebase messaging package 10.0.0, I get error in console and app doesn't open. Have tried many things mentioned in earlier post similar to this but nothing is working for me. Have tried deleting/removing pod files and folder and then repo update , flutter clean but still stuck with this error and not able to build app and error in launching it. Pls help..

```
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/gagansingh/Desktop/projectApp/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/FIRMessagingPubSub.m:229:26: error: definition of 'GULSecureCoding' must be imported from module 'GoogleUtilities.GULSecureCoding' before it is required
  NSData *pendingData = [GULSecureCoding archivedDataWithRootObject:topicsList error:&error];
                         ^
In module 'GoogleUtilities' imported from /Users/gagansingh/Desktop/projectApp/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/FIRMessagingPubSub.m:20:
/Users/gagansingh/Desktop/projectApp/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/Public/GoogleUtilities/GULSecureCoding.h:22:12: note: definition here is not reachable
@interface GULSecureCoding : NSObject
```

Podfile:-

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'


project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Facing same issue, please update if any solution

Comment: check the changes I made below in the answer and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any body trying to achieve the same.These are the changes below I made in the pod file. First delete Podfile.lock and Pods folder and make the changes in pod file as done here and then flutter clean and then run again. You might face the error again because it wouldn't have found the pods folder and pods file.lock and must have created the new ones by itself. Check if these have been created and then run again. And before all of this you have to add firebase_analytics of the same version of which you added other firebase packages in pubspec.ymal, irrespective of you are using it to not.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do

  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

to

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```